django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags and sharedpy-0.0.106
I am trying to move a deployment from one server to another to meet some organisational requirements. The components on the source server include:
Django 2.2.7
Python 3.7
Components on target (these versions are not fixed but must be current)
Django 4.2.13
Python 3.10.14
When running manage.py makemigrations I receive the following error:
File "/home/dtracker/dtracker/prime/models.py", line 2, in 
from sharedpy.django.utils import cache_get_or_set
File "/home/dtracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sharedpy-0.0.106-py3.10.egg/sharedpy/django/utils.py", line 10, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags'
Reference to django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags in settings.py has replaced with django.templatetags.static.
As per the last line of error, django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags cannot be found as it is not available in Django 3+.
My question is, does sharedpy-0.0.106 require django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags and if so, how can I remove the need to use sharedpy?
Tried to remove sharedpy however when running command received error stating it was required.

Problem solved. Updated .../sharedpy-0.0.106/sharedpy/django/utils.py :
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
To
from django.templatetags.static import static
